# get datetime from sql using php

Tags: php, sql

I have this issue where sql is already connected for php to retrieve data but I get undefined index whenever I try to get my date time columns (createddate and expirationdate)

file name: list-claimed.php

```
  <?php
    echo($lstOrders['createddate']);

  ?>

  <?php
    echo($lstOrders['expirationdate']);
  ?>
```

file name: list-claimed.vc.php (connected to list-claimed.php)

```
  require_once($routePath . "_mc/Order.mc.php");
  $mcOrder = new Order_MC();

  $usrcustomerid = $_SESSION['usrcustomerid'];
  $lstOrders = $mcOrder->SelectLst_ByUsrCustomerID($db, $pageNum, $limit, $usrcustomerid);
```

file name: Order.mc.php (database connected via list-claimed.vc.php)

```
  public function SelectLst_ByUsrCustomerID($db, $pageNum, $limit, $usrcustomerid) {
    $start = ($pageNum * $limit) - $limit;

    $stmt = $db->prepare(
      " SELECT orderid, productid, usrcustomerid, amount, amountrefunded, createddate, scheduleddate, useddate, expirationdate
        FROM `order`
        WHERE usrcustomerid = :usrcustomerid
        ORDER BY createddate DESC
        LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $limit
    );

    $stmt->bindValue(':usrcustomerid', $usrcustomerid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;
  }
```

[image: table order]

Comment: `$lstOrders` is a multi-dimensional array. Iterate over it. In the future please include your error messages in your questions.

Comment: i get undefined index "Notice: Undefined index: createddate in C:\xampp\htdocs\mwc_canuto\cards\list-claimed.php on line 82" the line is the echo

Comment: Yes, because you have a multi-dimensional array. The index isn't at the level you are trying to access it at. You have `0`, `1`, etc. at the top most level. Your columns are inside each index. Do `print_r($lstOrders)` and you can see the arrays structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return $rows` : You're returing an Associative array as result. To get values out of Associative array you need to loop through it.

For example:

```
foreach($lstOrders as $values){
  if(array_key_exists('createddate', $lstOrders)){
     $created_date = $values['createddate'];
  }
  if(array_key_exists('expirationdate', $lstOrders)){
     $created_date = $values['expirationdate'];
  }
}
```

When you're trying to get array values, its good practice to check if the index / key you're trying to access from array is exists or not. That way it will not give you that warning of undefined index.

Comment: tried this foreach loop in my html/php but i get "Warning: array_key_exists() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mwc_canuto\cards\list-claimed.php on line 106" the line error is the if